# perl expression "or" and subroutine "isa"

Tags: perl

I encountered this code, but I don't understand it .

```
$type->isa('UNIVERSAL')
  or eval "require $type"
    or croak $@;
```

1. I have refered to `perldoc` and I know that the subroutine `isa()` is checking whether `$type` has been blessed to the package `UNIVERSAL`. But in fact, all Perl classes are subclasses of `UNIVERSAL`, right?
2. I am confused about the two `or` terms. What do they mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Chained `or` melody

Perl’s `or` operator works just like `||` but has very low precedence, that is, how “tightly” it binds to surrounding code. Logical Or in Perl short-circuits, that is evaluation stops as soon as an operand evaluates true.

A common idiom in Perl uses short-circuiting for flow control, often related to error handling as in

```
open my $fh, "<", $path or die "$0: open: $!";
```

On success, `open` returns a true value. The result of `or` true when at least one of its operands is true, so on a successful `open`, perl does not `die` because the right-hand operand to `or` is not evaluated.

Chains of `or` operators can be extended arbitrarily. This is useful for specifying defaults. In the simple case, that looks like

```
my $name = shift or "Bruce";
```

If you have multiple fallback cases, put them in the order you want to try them.

```
my $name = shift or given_name $family_name or "Bruce";
```

The first case to succeed wins.

The code

```
$type->isa('UNIVERSAL')
  or eval "require $type"
    or croak $@;
```

is such a chain. Evaluation proceeds in the following order:

1. `$type->isa('UNIVERSAL')`
2. `eval "require $type"`
3. `croak $@`

If `$type` is the name of a package that already exists, then steps 2 and 3 are ignored.

Reaching step 2 means `$type` is not loaded, so now the code attempts to `require` it. If `require` succeeds, step 3 is ignored.

Reaching step 3 means the package does not exist and it could not be loaded. In this case, `croak` outputs the reason for the failure and exits the program.

### Has a certain module been loaded?

When called as a method, [`isa`](http://perldoc.perl.org/UNIVERSAL.html#%24obj-%3Eisa%28-TYPE-%29) has three forms:

> - `$obj->isa( TYPE )`
> - `CLASS->isa( TYPE )`
> - `eval { VAL->isa( TYPE ) }`

The third is a generic catch-all that is not relevant here. The first is what you described in your question.

The second is documented as

> When used as a class method (`CLASS->isa( TYPE )`), sometimes referred to as a static method), `isa` returns true if *CLASS* inherits from (or is itself) the name of the package *TYPE* or inherits from package *TYPE*.

The line just before the `or` chain in [`::_factory`, from SOAP::WSDL::XSD::TypeLib::ComplexType](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/MKUTTER/SOAP-WSDL-2.00.10/lib/SOAP/WSDL/XSD/Typelib/ComplexType.pm), is

```
my $type = $CLASSES_OF{ $class }->{ $name }
    or croak "No class given for $name";
```

Here, the value of `$type` is a string, so `isa` is checking whether the class named `$type` inherits from UNIVERSAL. As you noted in your question, *all* classes inherit from UNIVERSAL.

So what’s going on? If `isa` fails, the code calls `require`, so the intent of the `isa` check must be to determine whether a given class has been loaded.

### Does a certain package exist?

Remember that Perl classes and Perl packages are closely related. For a class to exist, a package by the same name must exist. Detecting non-destructively whether a package exists turns out to be tricky. Probing the stash `%Foo::Bar::Baz::Quux::` directly autovivifies. Perl stores stashes hierarchically, so you’d have to go spelunking as in

```
sub package_exists {
  my($pkg) = @_;
  $pkg =~ s/::$//;
  my @parts = split /::/, $pkg;

  my $stash = $main::{"main::"};
  while (@parts) {
    my $subpkg = shift(@parts) . "::";
    return unless exists $stash->{$subpkg};
    $stash = $stash->{$subpkg};
  }

  $stash;
}
```

A successful `require` modifies a special hash named [%INC](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%25INC). I’m not sure why the code doesn’t check `%INC`. Perhaps some types are loaded outside the require mechanism, or maybe the author was pleased with this delightful little hack.

Consider the source of [`sv_derived_from`](https://github.com/mirrors/perl/blob/b2a8d771f2f5721aa711c6ecdb42fdc198bfd244/universal.c#L147), which implements `isa`.

```
bool
Perl_sv_derived_from_pvn(pTHX_ SV *sv,
                         const char *const name, const STRLEN len,
                         U32 flags)
{
    dVAR;
    HV *stash;

    PERL_ARGS_ASSERT_SV_DERIVED_FROM_PVN;

    SvGETMAGIC(sv);

    if (SvROK(sv)) {
        const char *type;
        sv = SvRV(sv);
        type = sv_reftype(sv,0);
        if (type && strEQ(type,name))
            return TRUE;
        stash = SvOBJECT(sv) ? SvSTASH(sv) : NULL;
    }
    else {
        stash = gv_stashsv(sv, 0);
        if (!stash)
            stash = gv_stashpvs("UNIVERSAL", 0);
    }

    return stash ? isa_lookup(stash, name, len, flags) : FALSE;
}
```

Keep in mind that we are invoking this code with

```
"SomeClass"->isa("UNIVERSAL")
```

so `sv` contains the string `"SomeClass"`. `SvROK` checks whether `sv` is a reference, which a string is not, so we are always in the `else` branch.

At the end, the value of `stash` will always be non-`NULL`: pointing to the symbol table of either the package if it has been loaded or UNIVERSAL otherwise. Lookup succeeds for loaded packages and fails otherwise. Try it yourself:

```
$ perl -le 'print "strict"->isa("UNIVERSAL") ? "loaded" : "not loaded"'
not loaded

$ perl -Mstrict -le 'print "strict"->isa("UNIVERSAL") ? "loaded" : "not loaded"'
loaded
```

Comment: The `->isa('UNIVERSAL')` mechanism would catch packages that are in modules of different names `perl -le '{package example}print "example"->isa("UNIVERSAL") ? "loaded" : "not loaded"'`

Answer (score 3):

1. `isa` is being misused here to check whether a given package has been imported with `require` or `use`. `Package->isa('UNIVERSAL')` will return true if packcage `Package` exists, otherwise false.
2. `or` is being used in a [`short circuit`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) capacity. In expression `a or b`, `b` will not be evaluated if `a` has a true value. This makes no difference if the terms are variables, but if they are subroutine calls that have side-effects then it becomes an alternative to the `if` statement.

   The statement in question is equivalent to this code

   ```
   unless ($type->isa('UNIVERSAL')) {
     unless (eval "require $type") {
       croak $@;
     }
   }
   ```

   The overall effect is to check whether the module specified by the variable `$type` has been imported. If not then `require` is used to import it, and `croak` is called if that fails.

Comment: well ,thanks . May I ask if you have any knowledge about SOAP::WSDL?

Answer (score 2):

*Question 1*

[UNIVERSAL is the base class](http://perldoc.perl.org/UNIVERSAL.html) for all classes in Perl.

*Question 2*

`or` in Perl is a [low precedence operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Operator-Precedence-and-Associativity), meaning

- `A or B` is *true* if `A` is true, or if `B` is true, meaning, if either of the two conditions is true.
- *low precendence* means that the expression `A` above is evaluated *before* the `or`, provided that `A` operators precedence is higher than `or`. Which is likely to be the case as `or` (unlike `||`) has the lowest precedence in Perl.

In Perl, given the expression

```
A or B or C;
```

`B` is processed (evaluated) only if `A` is *false*, and
`C` is processed (evaluated) only if `B` is *false*.

Practically in your case, if `$type->isa('UNIVERSAL')` is *true*, Perl stops here and considers the whole expression *true*. If *false*, it will evaluate `eval "require $type"`: if true the whole expression is true, if *false*, it finally evaluates `croak $@`.

This is a quick way to do

```
 if ( ! $type->isa('UNIVERSAL')) {
    if ( ! eval "require $type") {
       croak $@;
    }
 }
```

Comment: well, thanks .Ha , I have a more detaied look at function eval() and finally understand the whole expression.May I ask if you know something about SOAP::WSDL ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know SOAP::WSDL.

Answer (score 1):

with `or`, perl will perform the right-side sentence only if the left-side execution returns a [non-false value](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=what%20is%20true%20and%20false%20in%20Perl?)